# Choosing between AWS RDS MySQL instance r4 vs m5

Tags: mysql, database, performance, amazon-rds

I am currently trying to understand the difference between 2 **AWS RDS MySQL** instance :

```
db.r4.large vs db.m5.large
```

Through r4 is costlier a bit, it offers 15.25 GiB Memory when compared to the 8 offered by m5. But the Max. bandwidth of m5 is 3500 compared to 437 of r5.

Can someone explain the difference here and which would be a better instance, if there would be more read queries than write in the database, around say 5 reads per second, with 100% utilization every day. (Ignoring the concept of read replica). Or is there a cheaper, better selection?

Answer (score 1):

5 reads per second?  Both configurations are over-kill even for 50 reads/sec.

What do you mean by 100% utilization?  That someone might be connected at any instance?  No problem.

Anyway, with any cloud service, you can start small and upgrade on demand.  It's not like buying a hunk of metal, where you are stuck with it if it is not powerful enough.